# How to delete items attachement from sharepoint List using pnpjs?

Tags: sharepoint, vuejs2, sharepoint-2013

Hi Im trying to delete attached item from list items first and then upload new attach file in sharepoint using pnp js (in vuejs)!
i trace the code and delete part is runnging but i dont konw why attached file doesnt delete!!!

this is my code for deleting attached item

```
      public async DeleteItemsAttachment(itemId: number): Promise<any> {
        let item = pnp.sp.web.lists.getById('{128EF67A-FDSF-4F42-8E8F-D3FC9523273E}').items.getById(itemId)
        return await item.attachmentFiles.deleteMultiple()
      }

  public async AddanAttachment(itemId: number, fileName: string, arrayBuffer: File): Promise<any> {
    let item = pnp.sp.web.lists.getById('{128EF6AA-FD8F-4F42-8E8F-D3FC9523273E}').items.getById(itemId)
    return await item.attachmentFiles.add(fileName, arrayBuffer)
  }

uploadFile(){
  if (this.itemId != null && this.myfiles) {
        if (this.HasUploadFile) {
          this.spService.DeleteItemsAttachment(this.itemId).then(response => {
            this.AddAnAttachmentToRecord()
          }).catch(e => {
            this.message = ` exception : ${e}`
          })
        }
        else {
          this.AddAnAttachmentToRecord()
        }
}
```

How can i solve my problem?
where is wrong area of my code?

Answer (score 4):

According to [`attachmentfiles.ts`](https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-JS-Core/blob/master/src/sharepoint/attachmentfiles.ts#L70) `deleteMultiple` function expects *the array of attachment file names*, so attachments could be deleted by explicitly providing file names:

```
item.attachmentFiles.deleteMultiple("{attachment-file-name-1}","{attachment-file-name-2}")
```

or (more dynamic way) by reading attachment names and specifying it in `deleteMultiple` function:

```
let item = sp.web.lists.getByTitle(listTitle).items.getById(itemId);
//1. get all attachments
let attachments = await item.attachmentFiles.get(); 
let attachmentNames = attachments.map(a => a.FileName);
//2. delete all attachmanents
await item.attachmentFiles.deleteMultiple(...attachmentNames);
```

Comment: thank you so much.it was very very helpful for me.again thank you